# How do I list all existing objects in an Excel Workbook to a text file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a rather large Excel file that has changed over time, and I want to compare  all of the objects in every sheet (charts, buttons, sliders, drop-downs) from an older version to see what has been added (or removed).

Is there a way to do this using VBA?

Comment: Do you just want the object names?

Comment: We're getting an "Excel found unreadable content in <filename.xlsm>. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?" error message when Excel 2007 users try to open this workbook.  I thought there might be some new object on which Excel 2007 was choking, but comparing objects between a current version and an older version that can be opened didn't show anything significantly different.  Any thoughts on where to look?

Answer (score 8):

Something like this to go through each sheet and produce a list that can be sorted by sheet, object type or object name.

```
Sub Dump()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim Sh As Shape
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\temp\summary.csv")

objFile.writeline "Sheet, Object Type, Object name"
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each Sh In ws.Shapes
        objFile.writeline ws.Name & "," & TypeName(Sh) & "," & Sh.Name
    Next
Next
objFile.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a macro that will loop through each shape (which includes charts and dropdowns), and write the name of that object to a new line in a Text file.  Note, this text file doesn't have to exist already, it will be created automatically:

```
Sub test()
Dim objFSO As Object, objFile
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\[whatever]\Documents\text.txt", 2)
objFile.Write "" 'This clears the text file

Dim obj As Shape

For Each obj In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    sWrite = obj.Name & "; height: " & obj.Height & "; width: " & obj.Width
    Debug.Print sWrite
    objFile.WriteLine sWrite
Next obj
objFile.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not as easily as you might hope.

You can't just loop through "all objects". Because worksheets aren't structured that way. Worksheets have `ChartObjects` `ListObjects` `Shapes` etc.

For each of those you could loop using

```
for i = 1 to activesheet.chartobjects.count
    debug.print chartobjects(i).name
next i
```

but you'd have to check that all of those objects have a name property or else your code will throw an error.

Best advice: Google for each specific object you have E.G. "How do I loop through all charts on a worksheet" (which will lead you back to `ChartObjects`). Do this for all the types of objects you have. Then you can write a `for` loop for each class of object.

Comment: I've tried using `Shapes` and it seems to pick up all the objects I've tried so far (a line, rectangle, chart, and dropdown).  Is `Shapes` perhaps at the top of the hierarchy?

Comment: Nope, it just depends on what specific objects are in your workbook

Comment: For instance, they might all happen to be "Shape" objects. But you should check for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some functionality ('NEW) I found useful to the solution provided by brettdj.

If you want to include all ListObjects in your results, try this...
Simply adds a For Each loop which prints all ListObjects (like Tables) to the .csv output:

```
Sub Dump()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim Sh As Shape
Dim Lo As ListObject 'NEW
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\temp\summary.csv")

objFile.writeline "Sheet, Object Type, Object name"
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each Sh In ws.Shapes
        objFile.writeline ws.Name & "," & TypeName(Sh) & "," & Sh.Name
    Next
    For Each Lo In ws.ListObjects 'NEW
        objFile.writeline ws.Name & "," & TypeName(Lo) & "," & Lo.Name 'NEW
    Next 'NEW
Next
objFile.Close
End Sub
```